# SQL SUM() by value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a generic key/value data store in MS SQL Server. I have a UserDecimalData table defined as follows

```
create table [UserDecimalData] (
    [UserID] nvarchar(64) not null,
    [ValueKey] uniqueidentifier not null,
    [Value] decimal null
);
alter table [UserDecimalData]
    add constraint PK_UserDecimalData primary key clustered ([UserID], [Date], [ValueKey]);
```

and as an example, here is some data that uses a GUID ending with 0001 to indicate an individual's score in a game, and a GUID ending with 0002 to indicate which team a user is on.

```
UserID  ValueKey                                Value
Dave    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001    35
Dave    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002    1
Phil    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001    35
Phil    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002    1
Pete    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001    35
Pete    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002    2
```

I can easily find the score for an individual by searching for their UserID + ValueKey ending with 0001. I can also find out which team an individual is in by searching for their UserID + the value of the row where the ValueKey ends with 0002.

My question is, how can I get a list of team scores? In this case team 1 would have 70 and team 2 would have 35.

Comment: You are coming up against one of the issues that leads to [EAV being considered an SQL Anti-pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/93124), this is almost certainly not the most efficient way to store this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select v1.Value as Team, sum(v2.value) as TeamScore 
from userdecimaldata v1
join userdecimaldata v2 on v2.UserId = v1.UserId and v2.[Date] = v1.[Date]
where v1.ValueKey = @clankey and v2.ValueKey = @scoreKey
group by v1.Value
```

OUTPUT

```
 Team   TeamSccore
    1   70
    2   35
```

Comment: Marked this as correct over other answer purely for readability.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select sum(udd.value)
from UserDecimalData udd
where udd.ValueKey like '%1' and
      exists (select 1
              from UserDecimalData udd2
              where udd2.ValueKey like '%2' and
                    udd2.UserId = udd.UserId
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--first way
with commands as (
    select UserID as UserID, Value as command
    from UserDecimalData
    where ValueKey like '%2'
)
select c.command, sum(Value)
from UserDecimalData u
    left join commands c on u.UserID = c.UserID
where ValueKey like '%1'
group by command
GO

--second way
select c.command, sum(Value)
from UserDecimalData u
    left join (
            select UserID as UserID, Value as command
            from UserDecimalData
            where ValueKey like '%2'
        ) c on u.UserID = c.UserID
where ValueKey like '%1'
group by command
GO

--results
--1 70
--2 35
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u1.Value, sum(u0.Value)
from UserDecimalData u1
    left join UserDecimalData u0 on u0.UserID = u1.UserID and u0.ValueKey like '%1' 
where u1.ValueKey like '%2'
group by u1.Value 

GO
```